# How to use Bing Cached pages for crawling

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler, search-engine, bing

Currently I'm crawling websites using Google Cache where it has a copy of the websites. I'am just using
`http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache: + 'URL of the website'`
to get google cached webpages. But now for some reasons I'm shifting from Google to Bing. So in Bing is there any similar way of doing this.

I know i can enter into Bing cached webpages by clicking on the small arrow button and then choosing 'Cached' option, but to reduce crawling complexity i don't want to use that.
So exactly what i want is
`URL of Bing cache + 'URL of Website'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Bing does not provide a publicly accessible URL similar to Google Cache for accessing cached webpages directly. Bing's cached pages are only available through the "Cached" option in the search results, as you mentioned.